# SVG separately animation

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-svg

i am trying to code an Analog Clock using React Native, React Native SVG.
this must be set by hand. i don't want to code dynamic clock. (There are tons of them on the internet.) i want to code  just a static Analog Clock. i must controll hour hand and minute hand by hand (dragging).
hour hand and minute hand must be connected each other. when i drag and rotate the minute hand 360 degree, hour hand have to turn 1 hour too.

you see the code under...

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Animated, PanResponder, StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Svg, { Circle, Line } from 'react-native-svg';

/*
var width = Dimensions.get('window').width;
var height = Dimensions.get('window').height;
*/
var width = 400;
var height = 400;

const DraggableView = () => {

  const ALine = () => {
    return(
    <View >
      <Line    {...panResponder.panHandlers}
        x1={0}
        y1={0}
        x2={80}
        y2={80}
        stroke="red"
        strokeWidth="10"
        transform={Aci}
        />
    </View>)
};

  const AnimatedLine = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(ALine);

  const [X, SetX] = useState(0);
  const [Y, SetY] = useState(0);
  const [Aci, SetAci] = useState("");

  const panResponder = PanResponder.create({
    onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
    onPanResponderMove: (event, gesture) => {

      console.log(Math.atan(gesture.dy / gesture.dx) * (180 / Math.PI));
      //SetX(gesture.moveX);
      //SetY(gesture.moveY);

      SetAci("rotate(" + Math.atan(gesture.dy / gesture.dx) * (180 / Math.PI) + ")");
    },
    onPanResponderRelease: () => {

    },
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Svg height={height} width={width} position="relative" viewBox="-200 -200 400 400" style={{ backgroundColor: "lightgray" }}>
        <Circle r={180} cx={0} cy={0} fill="white" stroke="green" strokeWidth="3" />
            <AnimatedLine    />
            <Line
              x1={0}
              y1={0}
              x2={150}
              y2={50}
              stroke="blue"
              strokeWidth="8"
              transform="rotate(45)"
            />
        <Circle r={10} cx={0} cy={0} stroke="black" fill="black" strokeWidth="3" />
      </Svg>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  box: {
    backgroundColor: '#61dafb',
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
});

export default DraggableView;
```

[clock interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMByS.jpg)

(this will be an app for kids and it must be controlled by hand)

Comment: Hello, could you please specify what would be your question or what do you need help with?

Comment: i want to design an analog clock, but it will be static. student (between 6-10 age) will set hour hand and minute hand by dragging the lines). for example. i will ask to the child "show me the 9.30 am. and the student will set this clock by hand draggind the hour or minute hands. and he will show to me.

Comment: @dianaqqq i have tried to explain. thank you